# How can I get a FormPanel to POST JSON with ExtJS 3.1.0?

Tags: rest, extjs, form-post, formpanel

By default, a `FormPanel` in ExtJS 3.1.0 posts the form fields as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` when you call its submit() function.

Is there any way to get it to post JSON instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `getValues()` to pull the values and then `Ext.encode()` them and manually do an `Ext.Ajax.request({})` with this data as well.

Comment: Thanks, this is the same solution as the one given here: http://www.extjs.com/forum/showthread.php?p=433863#post433863

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to extend `Ext.form.Action.Submit` to encode the params as JSON instead of url-encoding them in the body.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this is definitely the direction I want to go in, but I'm just starting off with ExtJS and I'd rather get the basics working first before I start extending stuff.

Comment: Extending components is really easy to do: see the section "A Re-usable Template" in http://www.extjs.com/learn/Manual:Component:Extending_Ext_Components

Learn to extend now before you build too much crazy code!

Comment: This seems to apply to ExtJS 3.0 but might probably be useful nevertheless: http://www.yannlaviolette.com/2010/07/extjs-formpanel-sending-json-data.html

Answer (score 1):

You can override `Ext.form.Action.Submit.run`.

Just like this:

```
Ext.override(Ext.form.Action.Submit, {
    run: function() {
        // Your code here
    }
});
```

Comment: Even though it should not really be monkeypatched like this, I think it's a useful hint as to which direction to move to when defining a custom Submit action.

Answer (score 0):

Just put in params

```
var formData = App.formPanel.getValues(false);
Ext.net.DirectMethod.request({ 
     url: '/Product/Save',
     params: formData,
     success: function(jsonResult){
     }
});
```

or

```
App.formPanel.submit();
```

Before set a `App.formPanel.url = '/Product/Save'`